# swift for loop arrays within array

Tags: for-loop, multidimensional-array, swift3

I'm using arrays within an array. something like 
**var arrs = [[String()]]**

then for in loop through-

```
for i in 0..<arrs.count {
   if arrs[i].contains(textField.text!) {
     self.arr[i].append(field.text!)
  } else {
     self.arr.append([textField.text!])
  }
}
```

well, it only works first  two inserts 
[["hi", "hi"]]
then when i add another string "hi" this happens.

[["hi", "hi"], ["hi"]]

What i'm trying is, if "hi" is in the array append them within the "hi" section. if there is a new word, use a new section. so i tried "there" then this happens
[["hi", "hi"], ["hi"], ["there"], ["there"], ["there"]]

i really dont know why the if statement isn't working properly. any master's help will be appreciated! Thank you!

So i tried it with @Nirav's 2nd answer and it worked perfect with Strings! 
then i tried it with my own small class(just a variable string) i got an error argument label missing 'where'
the class looks like this
the changed **var arrs = [[String()]] to var arrs:[[CheckIt]] = []**

As per request! updated all codes and the error im getting

```
class CheckIt {
    var test:String!

    init(test:String) {
        self.test = test
    }
}

var arrs:[[CheckIt]] = []
let testIt = CheckIt(test: "hi")
let testIt2 = CheckIt(test: "there")
let testIt3 = CheckIt(test: "bye")
let testIt4 = CheckIt(test: "terry")
arrs.append([testIt])
arrs.append([testIt2])
arrs.append([testIt3])
arrs.append([testIt4])


if let index = arrs.index(where: {$0.test.contains(testIt)}) {
    print(index)
}
```

and the EXACT error message im getting - 
Error: Value of type '[CheckIt]' has no member 'test'

Comment: You want to add same word in same array ? means result should be `[["hi", "hi","hi"], ["there","there", "there"]]` ? instead of your current result ?

Comment: thats right! but somehow my code is not working as [["hi", "hi","hi"], ["there","there", "there"]]. its weird or am i missing something?

Comment: Have you tried my below solution, is it working now ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you need to `break` the loop in `if` and need to add new array only if there is no array match condition otherwise it will go further.

```
var found = false
for i in 0..<arrs.count {

    if arrs[i].contains(textField.text!) {
        arrs[i].append(textField.text!)
        found = true
        break
    } 
}
if !found {
    arrs.append([textField.text!])
}
```

But this is not Swifty way what you need is to use [`index(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1688966-index) and don't need to use `for loop`.

```
if let index = arrs.index(where: { $0.contains(textField.text!) }) {
    arrs[index].append(textField.text!)
}
else {
    arrs.append([textField.text!])
}
```

Comment: my god! that worked! Thanks Nirav! (D for deadpool?), so i assume that index(where) is one good swifty way to look in the arrays! Thanks new learning! can you pls explain me when to use $0? i know that $0 will be used as a property within the array. but that is all! Thank again!

Comment: like $0 when to use  it?

Comment: @Terry Welcome mate, `$0` represent the each elements of array one by one in the closure because `index(where:)` iterate though array and if fine condition true it will no go further and stop it

Comment: @Terry Also there is problem in previous for loop answer I have corrected it check that too.

Comment: Ok, I faced some little issue with your second answer. Basically the index(where:) get an error if i try other than string type. for e.g. small class i've made. (the class is also to store some strings) self.message.index(where: {$0.contains(userID)}) and seems its not detecting the method. any idea? error says argument label 'where' is missing @Nirav

Comment: @Terry Edit your question with your class because here `$0` represent object of your class type so you need to access instance property after with which you want to check string contains or not

Comment: Thanks for your fast response and i did change the question. Would you please help me once more time? :D Thank you

Comment: @Terry As I mentioned in my previous comment you just need to access property of your class with `$0` so it is simply `if let index = arrs.index(where: { $0.test.contains(textField.text!) }) {`

Comment: HI again, i did try that actually and got a error value of type '[arrs]' has no member 'test' i definitely do have var test:String in my class. i'm not sure why. brain freeze! lol

Comment: @Terry instead of arrs you need to use `self.message`

Comment: sorry for the mistake! it is arrs Not self.message.. I was studying more of your code and got it mixedup! yes it is arrs! and getting error with [arrs] does not have 'test'

Comment: @Terry Edit your question with your current trying code your actual class and also show me the declaration of arrs

Comment: Yes all updated. with exact error im getting! Thank you for your time and knowledge

Comment: @Terry The problem is in your declaration of your array You are creating 2d array when you want array like `var arrs:[CheckIt] = []` and then add elements in array like `arrs.append(testIt) 
arrs.append(testIt2) 
arrs.append(testIt3) 
arrs.append(testIt4)` Or just `arrs = [testIt, testIt2, testIt3, testIt4]`